# Summary from 5 pick lists

Tags: formula, picklist

I have 5 pick lists, each pick list is a review and i need to have an average rating from all the selected pick list values.
The pick list values have strings and i need to give average rating as integer.
Ex -
Quality of work-
pick list values-
1.Superior work production
2.Very good Producer
3. Volume of work
4.Require close work
5.Very slow.
I have 5 such pick lists and i need to calculate average from the lists.

Comment: Add more details.  Is this in VF page or a formula?

Comment: Formula fiwld. It is.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use a combination of functions to get this value.

Something like this:

```
(
  value(left(text(field1),1))+
  value(left(text(field2),1))+
  value(left(text(field3),1))+
  value(left(text(field4),1))+
  value(left(text(field5),1))
)/5
```